# Windows 11 Infotip issue - SD card based images not showing image dimensions on mouseover

Tags: registry, tooltip, sd-card, windows-explorer, windows-11

hoping someone can help as i have had a real issue with this.

Just started with windows 11 and trying to get some work done and found a quality of life issue i would like to solve.

So in windows when you mouseover an image in windows explorer the infotip pops up and one of the bits of information it gives is the image dimensions. (for jpg, png etc etc)

on my surface laptop i have my main c: drive and then my storage drive is a large SD Card.
On the SD card I have a alot of files and images that i work with and process but far too many to put on the main hard disk.

In Windows explorer
When i have an image on the C: drive I mouse over it and the infotip displays the dimensions of the image alongside other information.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSPwU.png)

when i copy or move that same image to the SD card the infotip no longer shows dimensions (see my reply below with images)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFPeh.png)

Its amazing what little things you miss when they are gone.

I have done some research and spent a couple of days trying out the solutions i found and not getting anywhere.

these solutions involved going into regedit and finding the file type in hkey_classes_root\systemfileassociations.jpg .png etc etc

there are also some other posts saying other places to go to add the value System.Image.Dimensions
into the infotip registry key for the appropriate file type.

I have made sure that this is present in all these various infotip keys but it is not causing the infotip to display the correct information.

Is there a seperate set of keys that control the infotips in the SD card locations, I can't believe i am the only person that has found this, however it seems that there is no one talking about a solution to it.

I really hope one of you amazing people can help me work this out as i do alot of work with adding images to a website and the images have similar names, same preview but dimensions are their biggest differentiation and so i have gotten used to using the infotip when choosing the images i need for each given situation.

Thanks in advance for your time

I have done alot of research into this (although hard to write a good search query)
I have tried finding the registry keys for the image file handling and adding the System.Image.Dimensions string into the infotip key

I was hoping that this would solve the issue however it seems that there is a difference in the way the infotip is handled on internal drives and on sd cards for the same files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i have found the answer to this finally so will add it here as an fyi

for external drives the infotip is handled by the quicktip regkey

you find this in
computer\HKEY\CLASSES_ROOT*

Find the Quicktip String

add the properties you need in there....you can find the properties here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/image-bumper